# $\ker \varphi_p \subset (\ker \varphi)_p$ where $(\cdot)_p$ is taking the stalk of sheaves at the point $p$ (Diagram inside!).

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits, diagram-chasing

I've already proven that $(\ker \varphi)_p \subset \ker \varphi_p$ using a commutative diagram and the definition $F_p = \lim\limits_{\longrightarrow \\ U \ni p} F(U) = \bigsqcup\limits_{U \ni p} F(U)/ \sim$ where $[x] = [y]$ in the equivalence relation $\iff \rho_{UW}(x) = \rho_{VW}(y)$ for some $W \subset U \cap V$ open sets in the topology $X$.  I got that from Wikipedia article for direct limit.  Where $\rho_{UV}$ are the restriction maps of the sheaf $F$.

So I have a morphism of sheaves $\varphi : F \to G$, which induces $\varphi_p : F_p \to G_p$.  Intuitively it seems like if we assume $[x] \in \ker \varphi_p$ it's going to take a "subtraction trick" to show that $y \sim x$ for some $y \in \ker \varphi(U)$.  I'm just not sure where to deploy this trick.

The sheaves are abelian group-valued.

Any ideas?

---

[image: Diagram of involved direct limits]

The red and the blue represent two different diagram chases.  First we assume (blue) $[x] \in \ker \varphi_p$.  That's as far as I've gotten and shows that I did some work. :)

Diagram drawn using: https://www.mathcha.io/

---

$j$ is the inclusion map I proved in the converse direction on paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x \in F_p$ is in $\ker(\varphi_p)$.  Then there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and $\bar x \in F(U)$ such that $(\bar x)_p = x$.  Furthermore, since $(\bar x)_p \in \ker(\varphi_p)$, we have that $[\varphi_U(\bar x)]_p = 0 \in G_p$.  Therefore, there exists some neighborhood $V \subseteq U$ of $p$ such that $[\varphi_U(\bar x)] |_V = 0$.  But then $[\varphi_U(\bar x)]|_V = \varphi_V(\bar x |_V)$.  So, $\bar x |_V \in [\ker(\varphi)](V)$, and $[\bar x |_V]_p = x$.

Comment: From the definition of stalk as a direct limit.  (More generally, any element of $\varinjlim_{\lambda \in \Lambda} A_\lambda$ is the image of something in $A_\lambda$ for some $\lambda$.)

Comment: So "Therefore, there exists some neighborhood..." is since $[\varphi_U(\overline{x})]_p = [0]_p$ so by definition of direct limit, there exists some $W \subset V_0 \cap U$, such that $r_{UW}(\varphi_U(\overline{x})) = r_{V_0W}(0)$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I'm going to draw this up in the same diagram for my own clarity and for future askers.  I will go ahead and select this is as the answer though :)

Comment: Could you clarify the last equality?  See my diagram chase below.  So how do we get $\rho_{UV}(\overline{x}) = [x]$?  I'm not seeing it in the diagram.

Comment: The point is that both $\bar x$ and $\rho_{UV}(\bar x)$ have the same image in the direct limit.  i.e. if $\alpha_U : F(U) \to F_p$ are the maps from the direct limit, then $\alpha_U = \alpha_V \circ \rho_{UV}$.

Comment: Assuming that for fixed $V$, $(\ker \phi)_p := (\ker \phi_V)_p \subseteq F(V)$, is the following wrong? : $s \in \ker \phi_V \implies \phi_V(s) = 0 \implies \phi_V(s)\big|_x = 0 \implies \phi_x(s_x) = 0 \implies s_x \in \ker \phi_x$, where the third implication follows from the commutative diagram of $\phi_V$ and $\phi_x$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense in general to say $(\ker \phi)_p \subseteq F(V)$.  Instead, $\ker\phi$ is a subsheaf of $F$, so $(\ker\phi)_p \subseteq F_p$.  But in general, the map $F(V) \to F_p$ does not have to be injective: for example, if $F$ is the sheaf of continuous functions on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then you can have a continuous function on $(-1, 1)$ which is zero on a neighborhood of 0 without being zero on the whole open set $(-1, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Diagram chase of the situation]

According to answerer's textual diagram chase.

Comment: No votes because of messy diagram chase.  I know... I will in the future try to make prettier diagrams.  Note though, a solution manual to Hartshorne does this proof using the kernel / cokernel properties of a sheaf of abelian groups within some abelian category.  That is probably the better method; however, diagram chases are fun sometimes.